# Pre-commit feature in TeamCity and manual check out with Perforce VCS

Tags: version-control, teamcity, perforce, pre-commit, teamcity-9.0

I am trying to integrate TeamCity with my Perforce repo. Since the Perforce VCS takes forever to checkout with TeamCity VCS integration, I'd prefer checking out manually. How do I achieve pre-commit with manual checkout, how does TeamCity know when to apply the patch in a manual checkout process?

Comment: What do you mean by "manual checkout"?

Comment: Manual checkout means "VCS checkout mode = Do not checkout files automatically"

Answer (score 0):

What takes forever exactly: time to detect changes in VCS or the checkout itself? I assume you've already seen this page: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Perforce

When you perform a pre-commit the TC server is sending a patch to TC agent to run tests with this changes but I think there is also a patch sent to update agent working copy to latest one from VCS repo.

How do you imagine manual checkout and pre-commit to work? Can you describe it step by step?